# How do I sort on a second column in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi

I have a table of values from Analysis Services.
The table is sorted by descending quantity, and I would like when there are the same quantities like the 6 in the picture below, how can I sort the Gross Euros in descending order too?

[image]

Thank you for your help,

Comment: Populate a Rank column and sort Gross Euros column by Rank column

Comment: Add a calculated column?

Comment: you can write a Measure

Comment: How do you make this measure, please?

Comment: It's with analysis services and therefore not Power Query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First write a measure

`Measure = SUM(Data[Gross Euros])`

Then write a Rank measure

```
Rank = RANKX(ALLEXCEPT(Data, Data[Quantity]), [Measure])
```

Sort Quantity column by descending order by clicking arrow in header then press shift button and sort Rank column in ascending order

[image]